# Gatsby slug next/previous issues after adding `/blog${node.fields.slug}` to createPage

Tags: url, gatsby, slug

I am experiencing something strange and I have tried many work-arounds with no prevail.

I am trying to append "blog" to my templates' urls like so..

```
createPage({
      path: /blog${node.fields.slug}, // this line
      component: blogPost,
      context: {
        slug: post.node.fields.slug,
        previous,
        next,
      },
    })
```

Which works fine. So I used the same approach to account for the next/previous Links.

`<Link to={blog${next.fields.slug}} rel="prev">` (next example)

But when I go to an article e.g. `blog/category/hello-category` and try to click on a next or previous article e.g. `/blog/category/hello-category2`, the path is appending the current path and the next path - like so.

`/blog/category/hello-category/blog/category/hello-category2`

Can anyone help?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The missing leading slash was causing this issue.

`<Link to={`/blog${next.fields.slug}`} rel="prev">`

"Without the slash in the beginning it assumes links are relative to the root. It behaves same as normal HTML links in this regard. "